# How do I trace back to 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, console.log

My react app shows this in console whenever a specific page is hit. I am not sure on where to trace or look for the issue if I get the following.

```sh
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?059b:745)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js?059b:724)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?059b:645)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?059b:547)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js?b6e0:125)
    at Object.receiveComponent (react_devtools_backend.js:12701)
    at Object.object.<computed> [as receiveComponent] (react_devtools_backend.js:12418)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?059b:754)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js?059b:724)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?059b:645)
```

Comment: Unfortunately promise stack traces are not that useful sometimes.  This is due to the async nature.  Options like long stack traces that say Bluebird has will give you more info.

Comment: Not used this npm package, but looks like it might help. https://www.npmjs.com/package/trace-unhandled